# What would be ideal for a moderator to do if a negative voted (reasonably good) answer is flagged for moderator's intervention and review?

Tags: discussion, moderation, moderator-abilities

Here is a case of a reasonably good answer, which is not liked by a couple of users and got negative voted.

The member who answered the question believes that the answer does not deserve to be negative voted and flags for a moderator review of the answer.

Please note that this question is not about up-voting.

Can someone let know what is the best that a moderator can do in this situation? Thanks.

Comment: Nothing. Did you try searching?

Comment: If you're asking if moderators can reverse users' *legitimate* votes on a post, then no, they can't/won't.

Comment: Moderators are generally involved in cases which specifically cant be handled by the community..If a post is flagged with such a reason, it would most likely be declined

Comment: @CodeCaster : Does that mean even a genuine answer can remain negative voted if it does not attract a wider audience? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Absolutely correct.

Comment: @Bart : Thanks, you answered my query!

Comment: You could try your luck with the meta effect and link to that answer. If true that the question is reasonably good, it'll get some votes. Although it could go the other way as well.

Comment: @Bart comes out of hibernation to post on Meta, only to have me stomp on his glasses. Sorry.

Answer (score 11):

If such an answer were to be flagged, a moderator would respond with:

> **declined** — flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

In other words, there is nothing for us to do in that situation. The only time we get involved with voting is if there is clear evidence of fraud ([sockpuppetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sockpuppet_(Internet)) or [targeted voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)).

Votes are in the hands of the community, and as long as no fraud is being committed, users are allowed to cast votes however they see fit. Presumably, there *is* something wrong with the post, or it would not have been downvoted. You just aren't seeing it.

Moderators cannot reverse individual votes *even if we wanted to*, and we would refuse on principle to upvote a post in response to a flag begging for upvotes (even if we personally thought it merited an upvote).

Note, though, that if you *suspect* sockpuppetry or targeted voting has taken place, it is acceptable to flag a post on that basis. Use the "requires moderator intervention" option, which gives you a textbox to type into. Explain your concerns *in detail*, and why you suspect fraudulent voting. We have tools that allow us to investigate this, and if we agree you had a valid reason to suspect fraud, we will mark such a flag as "helpful" (even if we don't uncover any real evidence of fraud). There are cases where the system doesn't catch suspicious voting activity, and flags from users are a key way that we uncover and address this type of abuse.